# References for Grothendieck's "Pursuing Stacks" and "Esquisse"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory

Where can I find Grothendieck's "Pursuing Stacks"/"A la poursuite des champs" and "Esquisse d'un programme"?

Comment: http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~leila/grothendieckcircle/unpubtexts.php

Comment: Pursuing Stacks is also available from www.math.jussieu.fr/~maltsin/ps.html .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Really Martin's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62812/references-for-grothendiecks-pursuing-stacks-and-esquisse#comment157643_62812) should be the answer, but note Wikipedia also gives:

Alexander Grothendieck, 1984. "Esquisse d'un Programme", (1984 manuscript), finally published in Schneps and Lochak (1997, I), pp.5-48; English transl., ibid., pp. 243-283.

and the latter reference is :

Schneps, Leila; Lochak, Pierre, eds. (1997), [Geometric Galois Actions I: Around Grothendieck's Esquisse D'un Programme](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511758874), London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series, 242, Cambridge University Press, ISBN 978-0-521-59642-8

(This even has an [MR number](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1483106)!)

Answer (score 7):

In the light of the webpage [Grothendieck](https://agrothendieck.github.io/).

You can now see sections **1983, 1984** to see some other works around (for example the correspondence with Brown and the "Introduction to PS" then look at ["Récoltes et Semailles"](https://agrothendieck.github.io/divers/ReS.pdf) and later developed into an independent reflection

> *J’étais alors trop occupé déjà à écrire (le volume 1 de) “A la Poursuite des Champs”, lequel devait constituer aussi le volume 1 des “Réflexions” (mathématiques), pour me poser des questions sur ce qui m’arrivait. Neuf mois plus tard, comme il se doit, ce premier volume était terminé autant dire, il n’y avait plus que l’introduction à écrire, relire le tout, des annotations — et à l’impression...
> Le volume en question n’est toujours pas terminé à l’heure qu’il est — il n’a pas bougé d’un poil depuis un an et demi. L’introduction qui restait à écrire a dépassé le cap des douze cent pages (dactylographiées), quand ce sera terminé vrai de vrai il y en aura bien quatorze cent. Tu auras deviné que ladite “introduction” n’est autre que Récoltes et Semailles. Aux dernières nouvelles, elle est censée former les volumes 1 et 2 plus une partie du volume 3 de la fameuse “série” prévue. Celle-ci du coup change de nom et s’appellera “Réflexions” (tout court, pas forcément mathématiques). Le reste du volume 3 sera formé surtout de textes mathématiques, à présent plus brûlants pour moi que la Poursuite des Champs. Celle-ci attendra bien l’an prochain, pour les annotations, les index, plus, bien sûr, une introduction...* ReS):

- [Pursuing stacks](https://agrothendieck.github.io/divers/ps.pdf)

and

- [Esquisse.fr](https://agrothendieck.github.io/divers/esqfr.pdf), [Esquisse.en](https://agrothendieck.github.io/divers/esqen.pdf)
  (look there for some other works, like the [Rapport d'activité](https://agrothendieck.github.io/divers/rappI.pdf)).

> *C’est ainsi qu’est né Récoltes et Semailles. J’ai écrit les premières pages de l’introduction prévue au mois de juin 1983, à un moment creux dans l’écriture du volume premier de La Poursuite des Champs. Puis j’ai remis ça en février l’an dernier, alors que mon volume était pratiquement terminé depuis plusieurs mois(Entretemps j’avais passé un bon mois à réfléchir à la “surface structurale” pour un système de pseudo-droites, obtenue en termes de l’ensemble de toutes les “positions relatives” possibles d’une pseudo-droite par rapport à un tel système. J’ai également écrit “L’Esquisse d’un Programme”, qui sera inclus dans le volume 3 des Réflexions.). Je comptais bien que cette introduction serait une occasion pour m’éclairer sur deux ou trois choses qui restaient un tantinet floues dans mon esprit. Mais je n’avais aucun soupçon que ça allait être, tout comme le volume que je venais d’écrire, un voyage de découverte; un voyage dans un monde autrement plus riche encore et de plus vastes dimensions que celui que je m’apprêtais à prospecter, dans le volume écrit et dans ceux qui devaient suivre. C’est au fil des jours, des semaines et des mois, sans trop me rendre compte de ce qui arrivait, que s’est poursuivi ce nouveau voyage, à la découverte d’un certain passé (obstinément éludé pendant plus de trois décennies. . . ), et de moi-même et des liens qui me relient à ce passé; à la découverte aussi de certains de ceux qui furent mes proches dans le monde mathématique, et que j’ai si mal connus; et enfin même, dans la foulée et par surcroît, un voyage de découverte mathématique, alors que pour la première fois depuis quinze ou vingt ans, je prenais loisir de revenir sur certaines des questions que j’avais laissées, brûlantes, au moment de mon départ. Je peux dire, en somme, que ce sont trois voyages de découverte, intimement entrelacés, que je poursuis dans les pages de Récoltes et Semailles. Et aucun des trois n’est achevé avec le point final, à la page douze cents et quelques. Les échos, déjà, que va recueillir mon témoignage (et jusques y compris l’écho par le silence) feront partie de la “suite” du voyage. Quant à son “terme”, ce voyage sûrement est de ceux qui ne sont jamais menés à terme — pas même, si ça se trouve, au jour de notre mort... ReS*

Comment: Note that "Récoltes et Semailles" is  a completely different document from 'Pursuing Stacks', which is not clear from what you have written, so perhaps rewording the third line of your post might prevent confusion.

Comment: Sorry, what I wanted to show is in fact the interdependence of these meditations. If it appears to you that my changes do not achieve that, please feel free to edit the answer, you are better suited to say something about it. Many thanks

Comment: I understand what you intended.  I have made a minor adjustment to the wording. Please check that it still reflects what you wanted to say. (I was unaware that there was a preliminary version of R&S, and I cannot check my copy as someone borrowed it, many years ago,  and did not return it.)

Comment: @Tim "...did not return it" <-- oh dear!

Comment: @TimPorter I understand that we can see Récoltes et Semailles as distinct from Pusuing Stacks, but, in the mind of Grothendieck, these were very closely related and were supposed to be published together: Récoltes et Semailles was meant as an introduction, explaining how and why Grothendieck would return to Mathematics, and it grew and grew...